# GetType used in PowerShell, difference between variables

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What is the difference between variables `$a` and `$b`?

```
$a = (Get-Date).DayOfWeek
$b = Get-Date | Select-Object DayOfWeek
```

I tried to check

```
$a.GetType
$b.GetType

MemberType          : Method
OverloadDefinitions : {type GetType()}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Management.Automation.PSMethod
Value               : type GetType()
Name                : GetType
IsInstance          : True

MemberType          : Method
OverloadDefinitions : {type GetType()}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Management.Automation.PSMethod
Value               : type GetType()
Name                : GetType
IsInstance          : True
```

But there seems to be no difference although the output of these variables looks different.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

First of all, you lack parentheses to call GetType. What you see is the MethodInfo describing the GetType method on [DayOfWeek]. To actually call GetType, you should do:

```
$a.GetType();
$b.GetType();
```

You should see that `$a` is a [DayOfWeek], and `$b` is a custom object generated by the [Select-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) cmdlet to capture only the DayOfWeek property of a data object. Hence, it's an object with a DayOfWeek property only:

```
C:\> $b.DayOfWeek -eq $a
True
```

Answer (score 29):

Select-Object creates a new psobject and copies the properties you requested to it. You can verify this with GetType():

```
PS > $a.GetType().fullname
System.DayOfWeek

PS > $b.GetType().fullname
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

Answer (score 12):

[Select-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) returns a custom [PSObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with just the properties specified. Even with a single property, you don't get the ACTUAL variable; it is wrapped inside the PSObject.

Instead, do:

```
Get-Date | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DayOfWeek
```

That will get you the same result as:

```
(Get-Date).DayOfWeek
```

The difference is that if [Get-Date](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) returns multiple objects, the pipeline way works better than the parenthetical way as [`(Get-ChildItem)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx), for example, is an array of items. This has changed in PowerShell v3 and `(Get-ChildItem).FullPath` works as expected and returns an array of just the full paths.