# Powershell: retrieve variable type after using Get-Variable

Tags: powershell, variables

In PowerShell, I've a ScriptBlock variable:

`$my_scriptblock = {
    ....
}`

If I do `$my_scriptblock.GetType().Name` I get the type as `ScriptBlock` correctly.

But I'm using `Get-Variable` to collect all the user variables (I need it for some reason). But when I collect the variables using `Get-Variable`, they are converted to type `PSVariable`.

How do I get the variable type of a variable/object that is returned by `Get-Variable`?

Edit: more info

`$my_scriptblock_var = Get-Variable | Where-Object { ('my_scriptblock' -Contains $_.name) }`

Now, if you do `$my_scriptblock_var.GetType().Name` I get the type as `PSVariable`. Which is correct, `Get-Variable` will return an object it is designed to return.

My question is how do I get the original Type back?

Also, is there an alternate method I should consider to collect all user variables?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634555/gettype-used-in-powershell-difference-between-variables) help?

Comment: I think that I understand your issue, but could you please provide an [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @jrider: I looked at that before posting the question. My question is entirely different as the referenced question is not related to `Get-Variable` specifically.

Comment: `Get-Variable | % { $_.Value.GetType() }`

Comment: @PetSerAl: perfect, this works. Can you add this as an answer as well. EBGreen's answer below works as well. I'm not decent at powershell enough to judge which one is "Technically Accurate and Correct" way to use it. But it would be great to have this in the answers as well. - Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I have a way to do it, but I would say that the requirement itself is horrible.

```
$var1 = (get-Date)
$gottenVar = (get-variable -name var1)
$gottenVar.Value.GetType().Name
```

Comment: Use of `Invoke-Expression` is unnecessary here (and is generally discouraged). In your third line, just do `$gottenVar.Value.GetType().Name`

Comment: Good call. I still think there is an issue in the basic design of the script though. :)

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Variable` on its own returns the underlying variable objects. To just get the values use  `Get-Variable -value`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not looking to get the value of the variable. I am looking to get the type of the variable, which in my case should be `ScriptBlock`

Comment: You need to have the variable value in order to get its type. e.g. `Get-Variable -Value | foreach { $_.GetType().Name }

Comment: ah, makes sense. Just what PerSerAl says in the comment. Thanks,